# Is there a difference between initializing a variable with its declaration, or in a static initialization?

Tags: java, static, coding-style

The static initializer is called once by the classloader, which is exactly what I want, but doing the initialization outside a static code block is more readable (debatable). Is  there a difference between the two?

```
private static final Map<MyEnum, Cheese> cheeseCache;

    static {
        parserCache = new EnumMap< MyEnum, String>(MyEnum.class){{
            for(MyEnum myEnum: MyEnum.values()){
                put(myEnum, new Cheese(myEnum)) ;
            }

        }};
    }
```

or this :

```
private static final Map<Lab, LabResultParser> cheeseCache 
        = new EnumMap< MyEnum, String>(MyEnum.class){{
            for(MyEnum myEnum: MyEnum.values()){
                put(myEnum, new Cheese(myEnum)) ;
            }
        }};
```

Comment: Just curious, does the second one compiles? a for loop in variable declaration?

Comment: @JunedAhsan yes its in an anoymous sub class (double brace initalziation)

Comment: Use javap to disassemble the two and see how they differ.

Comment: (A simple static initialization with a literal/constant is generally mapped to a constant table initializer entry, but anything more complex the compiler swizzles into the `static` method.)

Answer (score 3):

It can affect the ordering - for example you could have:

```
private static final int declaredFirst;

private static final int declaredSecond = new Random.nextInt();

static {
    declaredFirst = declaredSecond + 1;
}
```

The initializers are executed in textual order. Of course, you could have just declared `declaredFirst` second:

```
private static final int declaredSecond = new Random.nextInt();
private static final int declaredFirst = declaredSecond + 1;
```

Personally I use static initialization blocks where I can't cleanly express the initial value in a single expression.

Oh, and if you initialize in a static initialization block, a variable can't be treated as a constant expression:

```
private static final int THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT = 10;
private static final int thisIsNotAConstant;

static {
    thisIsNotAConstant = 20;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT); // 10 is inlined
    System.out.println(thisIsNotAConstant); // 20 is not inlined
}
```

That's only rarely relevant, of course.

So in *most* cases it's just personal choice. Of course in your case, the ability to use more statements means you *don't* need to use the ugly (IMO) "anonymous inner class just to get some initialization":

```
private static final Map<MyEnum, Cheese> cheeseCache;

static {
    parserCache = new EnumMap<>(MyEnum.class);
    for (MyEnum myEnum: MyEnum.values()) {
        put(myEnum, new Cheese(myEnum));
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh Dear. Didn't knew about that last part. +1 for that.

Comment: @RohitJain: I hadn't thought of it until I was writing the answer :)

Comment: OOPs, the last part now became the 2nd last part. The one talking about constants.

Comment: @RohitJain: Yes, I guessed that was what you meant :)

Answer (score 1):

Both of your snippets create an anonyous inner class extending `EnumMap` just for the sake of initializing it. It would be cleaner to simply delegate to a method:

```
private static final Map<MyEnum, Cheese> CHEESE_CACHE = createCheeseCache();

private static Map<MyEnum, Cheese> createCheeseCache() {
    EnumMap<MyEnum, Cheese> result = new EnumMap<MyEnum, Cheese>(MyEnum.class);
    for (MyEnum myEnum: MyEnum.values()){
       result.put(myEnum, new Cheese(myEnum)) ;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is no difference as you are not doing any logic to decide what value should be assigned to the static variable.

From the [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.htm):

> Initialization value for a field in its declaration works well when
>   the initialization value is available and the initialization can be
>   put on one line. However, this form of initialization has limitations
>   because of its simplicity. If initialization requires some logic (for
>   example, error handling or a for loop to fill a complex array), simple
>   assignment is inadequate. Instance variables can be initialized in
>   constructors, where error handling or other logic can be used. To
>   provide the same capability for class variables, the Java programming
>   language includes static initialization blocks.

But I will go with the static block, because you will have an additional option to surround your initialization code in a `try/catch` if required. Assuming a scenario where something goes wrong while populating the enumMap, i may still want execution to proceed if the exception is not logically fatal.